# SSRS Bar chart expot to csv issue

Tags: sql, csv, reporting-services, export

In bar chart bar-name is shown in the exported csv as a seperate column,and also every column name contains '_label' in the end.any ideas to remove/change those things?

Answer (score 0):

The CSV headers are derived from the names of the textboxes that make up the cells of the grid. Make sure you change these appropriately.
Check and update, if needed, the 'Name' property within properties box.

Comment: sorry..is that so?but bar chart dose not contains any of text boxes...the bar's that contains data will show as separate column and value of that column is the chart's bar name.